# Create instance of joda DateTime from integer representing # of days since epoch?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

In my application, it saves a preference which is an integer that is the number of days since the epoch. (not relevant but it is used to create backups every x days)

Given this value, how can I reliably create an instance of joda `DateTime`?

I'm tempted to convert it to milliseconds by doing the multiplication  `value * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` but this will be wrong due to astronomy / solar time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying number of days into the number of milliseconds might be more readable if you use a library function. I highly recommend using Joda. :)

You have a number of days since epoch (GMT), and you want a DateTime (date + time + timezone). At a bare minimum, before you get further, you'll need to specify how you want to treat the time and timezone calculation.

The simplest way (which might not be what you intend) would be to create an instant in the local timezone representing the beginning of epoch, and then use `plusDays` to add the right number of days:

```
// in class - note that this will cache the current default timezone
private static final DateTime EPOCH_START_INSTANT = new DateTime(0);

// West of Greenwich, this will actually represent the "day" before.
// Day 0 will be Dec 31, 1969, local time.
DateTime localTime = EPOCH_START_INSTANT.plusDays(yourDayCount);
```

For the purpose of creating a backup every X days, you might instead want a LocalDate initialized at epoch (January 1, 1970), plus the number of days you want. That could then be changed to a specified local time relatively easily.

```
// in class
private static final EPOCH_LOCALDATE = new LocalDate(1970, 1, 1);
private static final THREE_AM = new LocalTime(3, 0);

LocalDate localDate = EPOCH_LOCALDATE.plusDays(yourDayCount);

// Midnight (or closest valid time thereto) in the default time zone
DateTime startOfDay = localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();

// 3 AM in the default time zone
DateTime threeAM = localDate.toDateTime(THREE_AM);
```

Comment: I originally calculated the day value by doing Days.daysBetween(epoch, now), and since the documentation states " Creates a Days representing the number of whole days between the two specified datetimes" I believe you will need to do `EPOCH_LOCALDATE.plusDays(yourDayCount + 1)`

Comment: @JamesWierzba Thanks for the edit. Yes, you might need to add 1, depending on whether you're storing/reading the day representing 23:59:59 or 00:00:01; that's left as an exercise to the reader :)

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33109591/642706) by Jeff Bowman is correct.

I'll show the same idea in the java.time framework, intended to succeed Joda-Time.

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the new java.time framework built-in. These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. They are inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310, and extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project.

I am assuming your count-of-day-from-epoch is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So we can use the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class, basically a count of nanoseconds from the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long myCountOfDays = 16_721L;
Instant instant = Instant.EPOCH.plus ( myCountOfDays , ChronoUnit.DAYS );
```

Let's adjust into a time zone. Choosing Montreal arbitrarily. Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 letter codes like "EST" or "IST".

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "myCountOfDays: " + myCountOfDays + " from epoch: " + Instant.EPOCH + " in UTC is: " + instant + " and in Montréal is: " + zdt + "." );
```

When run.

> myCountOfDays: 16721 from epoch: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z in UTC is: 2015-10-13T00:00:00Z and in Montréal is: 2015-10-12T20:00-04:00[America/Montreal].

Answer (score 1):

[According to the FAQ](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/faq.html#leapseconds):

> Joda-Time does not support leap seconds. Leap seconds can be supported by writing a new, specialized chronology, or by making a few enhancements to the existing ZonedChronology class. In either case, future versions of Joda-Time will not enable leap seconds by default. Most applications have no need for it, and it might have additional performance costs.

That suggests to me that you need not worry about that aspect.

But rather than doing the math, I would use [`DateTime#plusDays`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int)) or [`MutableDateTime#addDays`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html#addDays(int)) instead, using The Epoch as your starting point.

I assume, though, that your "days since The Epoch" is allowing for leap *days* (and that you're using the Gregorian chronology so JodaTime is, too).